# min max inside a linear program

Tags: linear-programming, duality

Although this sounds like a standard minimax problem, I'm not sure how to deal with feasibility issues.

Consider a maximin linear program

\begin{align}\max_x\min_y&\quad c^\top y\\\text{s.t.}&\quad Ay\leq b\\&\quad Cy\leq x\\&\quad Dx\leq f.\end{align}

Under what conditions can I swap the  maximin to minimax  and is there any duality theory that applies to this?

Note that y and x must be chosen to be feasible and we can assume that for any feasible x, there exists a feasible y. (We are not allowing infeasibility to count an $-\infty$.)

EDIT: changed minimax to maximin to clarify and added a condition.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner problem is actually trivial. For fixed $x$ satisfying $Ax\le b$, either $y \ge Cx$ and the inner problem has value $c'x$ or $y \not \ge Cx$ and the inner problem (using the usual convention for infeasibility in a max problem) has value $-\infty$. Since there are no other constraints on $y$, selecting $y=Cx$ is optimal in the inner problem, with value $c'x$.

So you are now left with a simple LP:\begin{align*}
\min\  & c'x\\
\textrm{s.t. }\  & Ax\le b.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using that convention for infeasibility. The challenge seems to be maintaining feasibility throughout the process. I'll edit the question to add that.